# Ionic controller is undefined

Tags: angularjs, ionic-framework

This is making me go crazy!

I am clicking on a row and all I want is to go to the details screen. It is a tabular application.

But I get the following error:

```
ionic.bundle.js:25642 Error: [ng:areq] Argument 'RoomsListController' is not a function, got undefined
```

**app.js:**

```
    // jobs list view
  .state('tab.jobs',{
    url: '/jobs',
    views: {
      'tab-jobs': {
        templateUrl: 'templates/tab-jobs.html',
        controller: 'JobsListController'
      }
    }
  })

  // rooms list view
.state('tab.rooms',{
  url: '/jobs/:jobId/rooms',
  params: {
    selectedJob : null,
    jobId : null
  },
  views: {
    'tab-jobs': {
      templateUrl: 'templates/rooms.html',
      controller: 'RoomsListController'
    }
  }
})
```

here is jobsListController.js:

```
$scope.showRooms = function(job) {
    $state.go('tab.rooms',{ selectedJob : job, jobId : job.id });
  }
```

Comment: you might get more views if you add an "angular" tag and show the application initializer as well (angular.module() I think?)

Comment: Is the RoomsListController JS file being loaded?